# Java 8 Stream group by and concatenate strings using a separator

Tags: java, java-8

I have list of objects which consists of bankId, IdentifierId and IdentifierValue. For each bank I have more than one identifierValue. My requirement is to create a map by grouping the List based on bankId and concate the identifierValue into a single string separated by /.

eg:

```
Bank of America, identifer-1,  123
Bank of America, identifer-2,  234
wells Forgo,     identifier-1, 123
```

I want the result to be a map like below

```
bank of America -> 123/234
wellsForgo -> 123
```

Class:

```
public class BankIdentifier {
    private String bankId;
    private String identifierId;
    private String identifierValue;
}
```

I am using Java 8 Streams groupby, but I am not able to get the identifier value separated by `/`

Comment: Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: Why do you want the slash separator? That is just a rendering issue. It is better to group by name mapped to a list of objects, which is supported out of the box. Rendering the list as a slash-delimited list of identifierValues is trivial using stream->map->collect(joining).

Comment: What you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would group the list based on `bankId` and the `identifierValue` accumulated into a single string separated by `/` delimiter.

```
Map<String, String> result =
                items.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(BankIdentifier::getBankId,
                                Collectors.mapping(BankIdentifier::getIdentifierValue, Collectors.joining("/")))
                        );
```

Ensure that you have a getter for `bankId` and `identifierValue` in order to use the method reference syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stream and then collect, grouping by, mapping and joining as in [Aominè's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47065236/1876620), or you can do it without streams:

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
bankIdentifiers.forEach(b -> 
    result.merge(b.bankId, b.identifierValue, (o, n) -> o + "/" + n));
```

This uses the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to concatenate the identifier values.